# How to add delete item option to Spinner dropdown list

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to let the user the possibility to delete the items shown in dropdown list of the spinner if clicks on the **"X"** button on the right side of each item, see the sample below.

If the user click on the item the Spinner should act like the classic Android default Spinner.

How should I extend and re-define the `Spinner` to work in this way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

**MainActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spnView3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnView3);

    ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
    aList.add("--Select--");
    aList.add("Md. Shahadat Sarker");
    aList.add("Developer");
    aList.add("ErrrorPoint");

    spnView3.setAdapter(new SpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_row, aList, aList));

    Toast.makeText(this, "Selected: " + spnView3.getSelectedItem(), 500).show();

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**spinner_row.xml (Layout):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spnItemName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:text="Item Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spnItemDel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="X"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Adapter:**

```
public View getCustomView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, parent, false);

        spnItemName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.spnItemName);
        spnItemDel = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.spnItemDel);

        spnItemName.setText(iName.get(position)+"");

        spnItemDel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //iName[position] = null;
                iName.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }
```

Full example is [here... download](https://github.com/iamsarker/android-apps/tree/master/DynamicSpinner)

**Edited Part:**

```
   if( /*Your condition goes here*/ ){
        spnItemName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else{
        spnItemName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I haven't understood how to create adapter class exactly. could you give me more details?

Comment: Nothing just simple. As like as others custom adapter. In getCustomView() method, spinner_row xml is inflated for each & every spinner items. And you get the component from the xml, then just add the action as you want.

Comment: another little doubt... assuming that I want to hide the "X" of remotion option when the dropdown list isn't shown, how could I do?