# Adding item from Spinner dropdown

Tags: android, android-widget

I would like to have a `Spinner` with drop down list containing one element on its end that would allow me to add new items.

Any ideas how to achieve such construction?

Comment: Well that is a point of my question. I am looking for ideas how to make such widget. Because as of now I have nothing on my mind. StackOverflow in not only to paste code or to fix bugs.

Comment: Well, this kind of questions are off-topic. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Go through this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Comment: Example of similar problem that got serious help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579230/how-to-add-delete-item-option-to-spinner-dropdown-list 
But thanks!

Edit:
-a specific programming problem, or
-a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
Therefore my question is not off-topic

Comment: @JakubW Create a spinner, with an icon next to it (right-side). When clicking on the icon, display a dialog that allows the user to enter a text (assuming that is what you want in the list?). When dialog closes, update the spinner's contents.

To the rest of you; you are not being very helpful...

Comment: @2Dee how is that a bad question? Is it because you did not have an idea how to answer it? 
For the first time I am disappointed in the SO community.

Comment: If you have to ask why it's bad, it's worse than I thought. But in the very remote case you're actually genuinely interested in improving (note : I don't believe so), then read [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/), [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315351/need-of-research-efforts-in-explain-short-code-questions), and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93937/how-can-we-discourage-people-from-answering-bad-questions-should-we/93939#93939)... Trying to attack me on my knowwledge is childish and counter-productive, I'm not the one who needs help...

Comment: Yet you put so much effort into proving me that I am so wrong. For what? Prove some random guy on the internet that you're right? You could have use small chunk of that time to pass me an idea and be on your way. I would be happy, you would be happy. Anyway I solved my problem, not going to waste more time on this topic.

Comment: *For what? * -> So you can learn from your mistakes. But you don't seem interested in that... But I strongly believe answering such a question would be counter productive for everyone involved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looked like "gold" community was to proud to help me out I tried some ideas out and it looks this one might be quite good.

I've created custom `ArrayAdapter`. Its role is to add additional bogus element at the end of the `List` to work as `NewItemBtn`.

**CODE**

**adapter**

```
public class AddingSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public AddingSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    addStaticElementToList(objects);
}

private void addStaticElementToList(List<String> objects) {
    objects.add("Add new objectt");
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

**spinner**

```
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int itemCount = parent.getAdapter().getCount() - 1;
            if (itemCount == position) {
                //bogus element chosen 
            } else {
                //select element
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```